# 'one and one is two' question

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

'one and one is two' is correct as you know. I wonder there should be whether 'am' or 'is' between 'he and I' and 'a monster.' 'he and I am a monster' or 'he and I is a monster?' I mean a group of him and me is a monster. For example, after you or I, verb 'am' is correct. I think 'he and I am a monster' is correct as 'or' and 'but'.

Comment: @Laurel No, it's related with 'following b in a or b' question.

Comment: Are you asking  about  "he **and** I ..." or "he **or** I ..."      ?

Comment: @James K Yeah kind of but when and takes the singular verb

Comment: "and" doesn't take the singular verb...  see the dupe!

Comment: @James K what about 'one and two is three'?

Comment: three is more than one so....

Comment: _One and one are two_, but _the sum of one and one is two_.